# PHP date and time stamp

Tags: php, timestamp

i'm busy with a wordpress module.
With this module people can show domain extensions for sale.

But now, there are coming new extensions so I want to make an option which allows the user to enter the releasedate of the extension in the backend of the website.
If the entered releasedate is today and this hour, customers are able to buy the extension by clicking on `buy`.

If the releasedate is tomorrow or later, there will be a warning text like "This exension isn't released yet, you can buy it at : `$releasedate`".

Now i made dropdown menu's to select a date like `3/5/2014` and a hour like `2 'o clock or 3 'o clock` or something else.

I put the selected date, which is a value for now, in the var `$releasedateday $releasedatemonth $releasedateyear $releasedatehour`.

I'm trying to make a timestamp, to make an if-statement like " `

```
if($releasedate =< $today) {

[*buy button*] }

else {
[This domain extension is going to release at $releasedate]`. }
```

Because I am not going to put down all the code of the dropdowns here, i give the variables a value. I have this but it doesn't work, can you guys please help me to make my values able to compare with the date and time of now?

```
<?php
$releasedatumhour = 14;
$releasedatumday = 14;
$releasedatummonth = 7;
$releasedatumyear = 2014;
$date = new DateTime($releasedatumday.'-'.$releasedatummaand.'-'.$releasedatumyear);
$releasedatum = $date->format('d-m-Y H:i') . "\n";
$releasetime = new DateTime($releasedatumuurs);
$releasedatum = $date->format('H') . "\n";
echo $releasedatum $releasetime.':00';
?>
```

Comment: `$datetime->getTimestamp() {comparison_operator} time()`

Answer (score 0):

To get the timestamp of the $date variable you can use the [DateTime::getTimestamp()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.gettimestamp.php) method

```
$release_ts = $date->getTimestamp(); //this would save the timestamp into $release_ts
$today = new DateTime('now')->getTimestamp(); //gets Timestamp of NOW

if($release_ts > $today) {
    ...
}
```

This should do the job.

Comment: But where do i have to put the 4 vars? $releasedateday $releasedatemonth $releasedateyear $releasedatehour and automatic the :00 to make it in hours without selecting the minutes

Comment: you could use  

`$dateString = $releasedatumyear . "-" . $releasedatummonth . "-" . $releasedatumday . " " . $releasedatumhour . ":00";
    $date = date_create_from_format("Y-m-d H:i", $dateString);`  
may not be the best way to do it but works

Comment: Tried it, but nothing will be shown on the screen<?php
    $releasedatumhour = 14;
    $releasedatumday = 14;
    $releasedatummonth = 7;
    $releasedatumyear = 2014;
    $dateString = $releasedatumday . "-" . $releasedatummonth . "-"         . $releasedatumyear . " " . $releasedatumhour . ":00";     
    $date = date_create_from_format("d-m-Y H:i", $dateString);

    echo $dateString;
    ?>

Comment: if i try your posted code everything works fine for me sorry can not say where the error is.

Comment: I fixed it, but now te problem is that when i echo it, i have to write  the format. Do i have to do this to when i compare $date with the time of NOW?

Comment: I would recomment to compare the timestamps (like in my answer) you dont have to write fromat then because you just have 2 numbers.